# Issue cordova plugins not found

Tags: javascript, cordova

Five minutes ago my app has worked fine but now it can't find this file:cordova_plugins.js
and cordova_plugins.json. Why?The version cordova is:2.9.0

The app on browser goes in infinite loop

Comment: my magic sphere says... that you should post some code

Comment: I've much code in backbone,javascript.I don't know what code can I post.

Comment: where are you referencing cordova_plugins.js?

Comment: Did you update the cordova codebase in any way?  If it just suddenly stopped working then you maybe accidentally deleted a file...?

Comment: I was testing some ajax call and modify html head in index.html

Comment: can you please post your html <head> block?